# Removing class from html elements

Tags: jquery

On a click event of Button 1 how can I remove the class 'selected' from only this section.  The classes of Button 2 should not be removed and the same goes for Button 2, if I click button 2, the classes of Button 1 should not be removed if the class selected exists.  I know `$('.small-button-1, .small-button-2').removeClass('selected');` removes everything.

```
<div class="block">
    <div id="abcd" class="lg_button">Button 1</div>
    <div>
        <div class="small-button-1 selected">1</div>
        <div class="small-button-2 selected">2</div>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="block">
    <div id="dcba" class="lg_button">Button 2</div>
    <div>
        <div class="small-button-1 selected">1</div>
        <div class="small-button-2 selected">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made it like this but had to rename some html tags to get it working here is my example 
http://jsfiddle.net/fKwGR/

The jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.lg_button1').click(function(){
        $('div.small-button-1.selected').attr('class','small-button-1');
        $('div.small-button-2.selected').attr('class','small-button-2');
        $('div.small-button-3').attr('class','small-button-3 selected');
        $('div.small-button-4').attr('class','small-button-4 selected');
        });
$('div.lg_button2').click(function(){
        $('div.small-button-1').attr('class','small-button-1 selected');
        $('div.small-button-2').attr('class','small-button-2 selected');
        $('div.small-button-3.selected').attr('class','small-button-3');
        $('div.small-button-4.selected').attr('class','small-button-4');
        });
});​
```

HTML part:

```
<div class="block">
  <div id="abcd" class="lg_button1">Button 1</div>
  <div id='button1'>
      <div class="small-button-1 selected">1</div>
      <div class="small-button-2 selected">2</div>
  </div>
```

```
<div class="block">
  <div id="dcba" class="lg_button2">Button 2</div>
  <div id='button2'>
      <div class="small-button-3 selected">1</div>
      <div class="small-button-4 selected">2</div>
  </div>
```

​

Comment: This isn't a lot of code.  In the future, can you post your code here?  If you still want to link to jsfiddle, that's fine.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean

Comment: Show us your code on this page, not just on a link to jsfiddle.  It's more convenient for people reading your code, it helps search engines find your answers (since the text of the code will be searched), and it prevents link rot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to get hold of the parent element and then use that as the context of your selector. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/VY5Md/ should achieve what you're asking for I think

```
  $(function(){
       $('.lg_button').click(function(){
           var $p = $(this).parents('.block');
           $('.selected', $p).removeClass('selected'); 
       }); 
  });​
```

This code gets the button that was clicked, finds the parent with class "block" and then removes the class "selected" from anything with the class "selected" within the context of that "block"

Comment: What the fiddle or when you apply it to your code? What version of jQuery are you using?